# mean reversion with Kalman Filter - Spread calculation

Tags: spread, kalman

[Ernest Chan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118460146) in its book "Algorithmic Trading" shows how to use the [Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/integrated3/kleeman_kalman_basics.pdf) for mean reversion pair trading.

I have seen that he uses the measurement prediction error for calculating the spread size. 
In other works, he bases the spread calculation on:

$$
e = y_{t} - \hat{y} $$

where, $ \hat{y} $ is the measurement prediction based on the state variable predictor $ \hat{x}(k+1|k)$ where $k$ is the time/measurement.

I was wondering what the advantage of using the measurement prediction error instead of the residuals is. With residuals I mean $y - y_c$ where $y_c$ is the estimate of the measurement based on the updated/corrected state variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Very old one, still unanswered... Can you clarify your question by clearly identifying the 2 cases you are comparing and the symbols you use? Because the usage you make of $\hat{y}$, $y_c$, $y$ and $y_t$ is not clear.